# When should we tag questions with [gramática]? When should we not?

Tags: discussion, tags

Over a third of our present 222 questions are tagged [gramática](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gram%c3%a1tica), many of them followed by something more specific like [ortografia](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ortografia) (our second most used tag). Grammar is clearly one of the site's major topics, but how should it work as a tag? As it currently stands, we could split the site's questions as:

- 37% [gramática](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gram%c3%a1tica)
- 63% not [gramática](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gram%c3%a1tica)

It fells to me that the tag is either too broad, or being misused. Is it used in other language sites in the network? Is there any guideline we could build upon?

Comment: I have noticed that [tag:grammar] has been misused in some questions. We may start by removing or changing the tag in these cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree that *gramática* is usually too broad. On the English SE site we try to use more specific terms than that whenever possible, but new posters are constantly using the *grammar* tag.  We clean these up when we have the chance.

Any collocation of *gramática* and *ortografia* is somewhat peculiar, in that “correct writing” is not usually consider a function of grammar *per se*. But it also happens on ELU that people use them together, at least until we edit them into something that fits better.